# Duration between type in and out in MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

[image]

> I am new MYSQL now i try something here is my query not accurate result

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(time))) FROM `officialbreaks` where type='out'

SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(time))) FROM `officialbreaks` where type='in'
```

Any buddy have work on that type of situation.

OUT REQUIRED

```
TIMEDIFF(time where type=in, time where type=out) 
3:35:30 time type=in, 03:35:30 time type=out
Output 0
```

Comment: join use on `userid` not `date`

Comment: It seems the database is badly normalized. Both `officialtimin` and `officialtimeout` should be in one table.

Comment: Rajesh kumar sorry for last query not correct query i update my question please review

Comment: Vipin and Rajesh i have query for where the type in and out calculate time duration that's my question

Comment: show what output you required...means do u want single row for single user like difference between first in and last out or else...

Comment: no no not first and last i ll use condition where type=in timediff type=out

Comment: First is always type=in and Second is always time=out. that can i use time in and out row wise calculate like in out in out ..etc

Answer (score 0):

You can try as per below-

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.userid, (TIME_TO_SEC(b.time) - TIME_TO_SEC(a.time)) AS 'time_diffrence' FROM 
(SELECT userid,`time` FROM mytable WHERE `type`='in') a 
JOIN (SELECT userid,`time` FROM mytable WHERE `type`='out') b ON a.userid=b.userid
```

It is a simple solution but there can be multiple out time against single in time and multile users etc. so there can be so many combination where query need to change.

Comment: Thank you for your responseThat's show an error #1052 - Column 'userid' in field list is ambiguous
And what is this b.time and a.time?

Comment: USE DISTINCT and with this answer are same repetition of time not really difference last code i already tested